# Custom HTML as FormField in Django

Tags: html, django, formfield

I have a project going in which i'd like to be able to have some custom html inside a form. The reason being that i would for example like to have a file/image browser inside my form so that i could select an image and have the url posted with the form without constantly having to modify the form and/or recreate the file browser inside a template.

After some research it seems to me that going with custom formfields looks like the way to go, although i can't seem to figure out if it's possible to have a custom formfield output custom html when the form is generated. It may be my google skills, although i kind of lean to thinking that there isn't really that much documentation on the subject.

Has anybody worked with something like this before?

Comment: You can add custom HTML in your form template. See this section of the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates

Comment: I know i can work with the form inside a template, but what i'm looking to do is create something like a form.field object so that i could just use 3 to 4 lines of code each time, instead of placing quite a lot of html / javascript into each separate template.

Comment: This might not be the most ideal or correct way to go about it, but what if you just included a template that represents your custom object in the middle of each form? You can pass additional context to your included templates by using the `with` keyword: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-include

Comment: After doing a bit more research, it looks like you might be able to use 'Widgets' to achieve what you want to do. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-classes

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but thanks for the suggestions. I will look into using widgets and if i can't figure out how to use that i guess i'll just go with the template thing.